# Scalar Potential formula

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $P$ and $Q$ be real functions from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$, $P, Q\in \mathcal C^1$, such that $\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x} $.

How can I show that $f(x, y) = \int_{0}^1 (xP(tx, ty) + yQ(tx,ty)) dt$ is a scalar potential of $F = (P, Q)$?

Comment: I tried to compute its gradient but I didn't really succeed.

Answer (score 1):

I will solve one part for you. We have

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}&=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\left(P(tx,ty)+x\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(tx,ty)+y\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}(tx,ty)\right)~dt\nonumber\\
                             &=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\left(P(tx,ty)+x\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(tx,ty)+y\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}(tx,ty)\right)~dt\nonumber\\
&=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\left(P(tx,ty)+t\frac{\partial P}{\partial (tx)}(tx,ty)\frac{\partial (tx)}{\partial t}+t\frac{\partial P}{\partial (ty)}(tx,ty)\frac{\partial (ty)}{\partial t}\right)~dt\nonumber\\
&=\int\limits_{0}^{1} \left(P(tx,ty)+t\frac{dP}{dt}(tx,ty)\right)dt\nonumber\\
&=\int\limits_{0}^{1} P(tx,ty) dt + t ~dP(tx,ty)\nonumber\\
&=\int\limits_{0}^{1} d(tP(tx,ty))\nonumber\\
&=P(x,y).
\end{align}

Comment: wow thanks! I see how it works now. I appreciate it Urnium!!

Answer (score 0):

To show that $\mathbf{F}$ has a scalar potential we need to show that $\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=0$. It is not difficult to prove that, for some scalar field $\psi$, $\nabla\times\nabla\psi=0$.  Now, 
\begin{align}
f(x, y)& = \int_{0}^1 (xP(tx, ty) + yQ(tx,ty)) dt\\
&=\int_{0}^1 \mathbf{F}\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\ t\langle x, y\rangle\  dt\\
&=\int_{0}^1 \mathbf{F}\cdot\frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt}  dt\\
&=\int_{0}^1 \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}\\
&=\int\int_R \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} -\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\ dA\\
&=\int\int_R\nabla\times \mathbf{F}\cdot dA\mathbf{\hat{z}}\\
&=0
\end{align}

Where I have used Stokes' theorem in the third to last line.